# Integrating a complicated function wrt to $t$

Tags: integration

I have two pretty similar integrals to be solved. I manage to solve the first one which is $\int_{-0.9}^{0.9}\frac{t^2-1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}(t-c)^2}dt$, where the solution involved $\arcsin$ as well as log function. The second integral is pretty similar to the first one given by $\int_{-0.9}^{0.9}\frac{(t^2-1)\sqrt{1-t^2}}{(t-c)^2}dt$, which I have no idea how to start. I know for sure it will be hideous as the first integral (took me 3 pages to write down the solution). Can someone please shed some light on how I should start integrating this function.

Comment: What is the symbol $c?$.

Comment: @shahrina What makes you think there's a closed form? Wolfram Alpha can't find one.

Comment: Note that just because $\int f$ has an elementary integral, it doesn't mean $\int \frac1f$ does too. Take $f=\ln x$ for instance.

Comment: @Jam When I type this into wolfram alpha I do recieve a closed form.

Comment: @user140776 That's odd. It doesn't return an answer for me. Ignore my earlier comment then.

Comment: WolframAlpha found the indefinite integral, but not the definite one.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah $c$ is a constant that I will vary at the end after the integration.

Comment: yes, it seems like wolfram alpha gave a closed form for the indefinite integral which involved arcsin and log function. the first integral that i manage to solve also has arcsin and log function involved. can someone enlighten me on how to do the first step of the integration? any ideas? Does anyone reckon partial fraction will work?